# Python module not found in docker

Tags: python, django, docker, dockerfile

I am trying to start my django project with Docker and it works fine until I add any apps.
I checked django code itself by running it with PowerShell and it worked fine.

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
COPY requirements.txt /code/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /code/
ADD . /authenticate
```

and docker-compose.yml file

```
version: "3.8"
   
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
  web:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

**"authenticate"** is the app name

I use `docker-compose build` and `docker-compose up` to launch project and I get following error message:

```
 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'authenticate'
```

**Edit**

INSTALLED_APPS code:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'authenticate',
]
```

and the project structure is

```
.
├── requirements.txt 
├── Dockerfile
├── docker-compose.yml
├── manage.py 
├── authentication         
│    ├── templates\authenticate             
│    │   └── home.html
│    ├── apps.py
│    ├── __init__.py
│    ├── admin.py
│    ├── apps.py
│    ├── models.py
│    ├── tests.py
│    ├── urls.py
│    └── views.py
└── my_project
    ├── __pycache__           
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── asgi.py
    ├── settings.py    
    ├── urls.py 
    └── wsgi.py
```

Comment: Could you show your docker compose service description as well?

Comment: Of course, I added it in the question

Comment: Could you show "INSTALLED_APPS"?

Comment: Also it would be great to see the directory/files structure of your python project.

Comment: Added all the info

Comment: In the installed apps, it seems that it should be **authentication** not **authenticate**

Comment: Completely agree with @LearningNoob - either rename package in file system or rename it in INSTALLED_APPS. If still will not work - we can also take a look on `apps.py`.